# Extract zip files with the latest name in each subfolder

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, batch, zip

**Situation:**
I have the following folder tree:

- Root\

  - doc1\

    - doc1-r000.zip
    - doc1-r010.zip
    - ...
    - doc1-r051.zip
  - doc3\

    - doc3-r000.zip
    - doc3-r001.zip
    - ...
    - doc3-r012.zip
  - ...
  - docN\

    - ...
    - docN-rM.zip

where each subfolder contains multiple revisions of a document in separate zip files. Both folder names and revision numbers are discontinuous. Almost all documents have different number of revisions. These are cloned from a remote FTP server, thus all have the same timestamp and the date information is gone.

**Goal:** The ultimate goal is to extract only the latest revision of each doc to the root.

**Tools:** Tools readily available are Windows 7, PowerShell 2 and 7-Zip, additional tools or updates can be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell with 7-Zip:

```
$root = "C:\adjust\path"

Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Recurse -Include 'doc*' | ForEach-Object -Process {

    $n = 0
    $dir_name = ($_.FullName) + '\' + ($_.BaseName)

    while (Test-Path "$dir_name-r000.zip") {

        $num = "{0:d3}" -f $n
        $test = "$dir_name-r$num.zip"

        if (Test-Path $test) {

            $file_name = $test
            $n++

        } else {

            ."C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" e "$file_name" -o"$root\$_.BaseName"

            break

        }
    }
}

"Done!`n"
Pause
```

This will extract the archive with the highest number from each folder which contains `doc` to a new subfolder in `$root`. If you don't need the subfolders simply remove `\$_.BaseName` from the `-o` option.

Comment: I was able to get the solution I needed by just making few modifications to your script and updating my Powershell, thank you so much. Since the revs are not continuous I just counted backwards from 999 :)